# Deploy laravel project on HTTPS and loading content with correct href during cross-origin requests

Tags: php, laravel, api, nginx, cors

I have the next issue. I deploy `laravel project` to the server on `https\ssl` domain. It loads 'OK' without rewriting `.httaccess` file because I have pre-config `nginx` settings. But when I try to get access to my 'API' from other domain `with cross-origin request` to this domain - I receive the error `"Blocked loading mixed active content “http://xxxx.xxx“"`. How you see it returns `"http"` host in error, and then also send me the error with CORS `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://xxxxx.xxx. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).`.

I tried force URL in middleware controllers, use `laravel-cors` libs, but it's no effect. I don't think that problem with CORS, I think the problem in configure middleware or api-middleware. For API I use `Dingo API`.

Answer (score 0):

In your middleware you need to set the header. Create a Middleware class and place the following in the handle method:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    return $next($request)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
}
```

Then add it to $routeMiddleware in app/Http/Kernel.php. Then use that middleware for any route you need to.

Comment: I already include `CORS middleware`. `'Blocked loading mixed active'` error appear, because in routes I used `slashes` on the end of the path. To avoid this issue you should trim it. And then i catch new error trying to write data to `DB`. When I send `POST` request without trying to write something to `DB` I return `Success status 200`, But when I try to write something to it - I reciive the next error `"Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://api.xxx.xxx/xxxx. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed)."`. How I can solve it?

Comment: You need to post your controller and router code. Are you sure you applied the middleware to the route? What do the headers look like?

Answer (score 0):

All problems was in `hrefs(links)` if you write `href` in front-end like https://site/api/news/ it's receive error, but when you write it like https://site/api/news it's ok... All you need remove last `'/'`. `API Frameworks` think that you want get all data from folder, because of that block it. It was `'Wrong endpoint issue'`